# the term export is not being recognized

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

```
export : The term 'export' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ export PATH=$PWD/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (export:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

i tried powershell but error persisting

Comment: You are passing a *nix shell command to Powershell, which doesn't work. Either use, say, bash, or use the Powershell syntax.

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: The PowerShell equivalent of your command is: `$env:PATH = "$PWD/node_modules/.bin:$env:PATH"`. Note that npm also comes with an `npx` command, which obviates the need for such an addition to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: "export" isn't powershell.

Answer (score 0):

If this actually needs to be done, use the PowerShell capabilities to make it platform agnostic.

```
$ExeDir = Join-Path -Path $(Get-Location) -ChildPath 'node_modules' -AdditionalChildPath '.bin'
$Env:PATH = $ExeDir,$Env:PATH -join [IO.Path]::PathSeparator
```